# Compiling is stuck on the previous compilation c++

Tags: c++

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <string>

   using namespace std;



   int main() {

     cout << "Hello";

   }
```

When I try to compile this program it still compiles the last program that was:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <string>

  using namespace std;


  int main() {

      int a, b;
      cin >> a >> b;
      cout << a + b << endl;

      return 0;
  }
```

I do gcc code.cpp(name of the file) and code in command prompt and this appears:

```
     c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cctefhtT.o:code.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to 
     `std::cout'
     c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cctefhtT.o:code.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to 
     `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> > 
     (std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
      c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cctefhtT.o:code.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to 
      `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
      c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cctefhtT.o:code.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to 
      `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
      collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My editor is sublime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the result of your previous program, because the compilation of your new program fails.

The reason why compilation of your program fails is because your program depends on code from the C++ standard library. Your program is not linked against the C++ standard library because you use `gcc`, which is the compiler for C. You need to use `g++` which is the compiler for C++.

Comment: Do you know why I cant delete the executable , it says it is open in code, what does it mean? I have everything closed. And thank you it dosent show those errors anymore.

Comment: @Derteckpt maybe because it is still running? Check your OS's task manager.